# plot 3D density plot use gglot/plot_ly

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggplotly

I have one `11`-dimensional vector which is a division of `[0,1]`:

```
Vec = seq(0,1,1/12)
```

and a `11-by-11` matrix

```
A = matrix(c(0.9024306 , 0.8452877 , 0.8141085,  0.7549162 , 0.6824799 , 0.6109678 , 0.5905854 , 0.5299411,  0.4550736,  0.3858676,  0.2143513,
         0.7819361,  0.8210354  , 0.8331744,   0.8182613  , 0.7622890 ,  0.7101383 ,  0.6931922  , 0.6408286,   0.5925585 , 0.5282755,  0.4037932,
         0.7213725 ,  0.8014270,   0.8334573 ,  0.8394664 ,  0.7965267  , 0.7557029 ,  0.7411934  , 0.6947566 ,  0.6590388  , 0.5987447 , 0.4968339,
         0.6747898  , 0.7823459  , 0.8286614 ,  0.8500438  , 0.8196929 ,  0.7884412 ,  0.7761882  , 0.7352614 ,  0.7087581 ,  0.6523485 , 0.5672221,
         0.6344532 ,  0.7626475  , 0.8205274  , 0.8546509  , 0.8372373 ,  0.8149571  , 0.8049617   , 0.7695615   , 0.7506879 ,  0.6982902 , 0.6272401 ,
         0.5953397  ,  0.7403922  ,  0.8086858 ,   0.8545969  ,  0.8517511  ,  0.8388487 ,   0.8313441   , 0.8020533  ,  0.7902309 ,   0.7423674  , 0.6845121 ,
         0.5607208  ,  0.7177988 ,   0.7945752  ,  0.8503988  ,  0.8623037  ,  0.8583240 ,   0.8533009   , 0.8301061   , 0.8242061 ,   0.7809468  , 0.7343530 ,
         0.5235966  ,  0.6901752  ,  0.7751871 ,    0.8410303 ,    0.8709305 ,    0.8772494 ,    0.8752120 ,    0.8593621 ,    0.8594394 ,    0.8218108 ,    0.7868039 ,  
         0.4792436 ,    0.6519074 ,    0.7454233  ,   0.8222904 ,    0.8770665 ,    0.8968215  ,   0.8988547 ,    0.8930324  ,   0.8996717  ,   0.8698448 ,    0.8479224 ,  
         0.4310832  ,   0.6026974 ,    0.7035051 ,    0.7909658  ,   0.8776638  ,   0.9136550  ,   0.9208403  ,   0.9277279 ,    0.9406499 ,    0.9208578 ,    0.9120395 ,  
         0.3622446  ,   0.5148011 ,    0.6215788  ,   0.7210252 ,    0.8646102  ,   0.9275842  ,   0.9438128  ,   0.9730440   ,  0.9930145 ,    0.9911498  ,  0.9985318),nrow=11,byrow=TRUE)
```

What I expect is like a scatter plot like the following:
[image: 3D]

each point represents a pair, e.g., `(0.08333, 0.08333, 0.90243)` etc.

I tried `plot_ly` to plot this, but failed. Can anyone shed lights on how to draw this? I truly appreciate your suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The A matrix can be the z argument to plot_ly`. Plotly figures out the dimensions from the matrix. In your case you would not need to add labels to the axis ticks, but you could add axis labels when the range of x and y values were not [0,1](although this does generate a warning despite being entirely successful):

```
if( !require(plotly) ){install.packages("plotly", dependencies=TRUE)
                       library(plotly)}
plot_ly(z = A, type = "surface", labels=list(x=(1:11),y=(1:11)))
```

[image]

And you can forget about ggplot2. It does not do pseudo-3D. Hadley is philosophically opposed to that type of visualization. The R package that  does this sort of plotting with interactive rotation is `rgl`.

Comment: Thanks! I am wondering if this ```plot_ly``` object can be more polished using the package ```rayshader```?

Comment: I suspect polishing could still be done in plotly. (I'm not terribly skilled at it, though.)  I don't see this data as gaining much from `rayshader`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one that is quite close:

```r
library(RColorBrewer)
library(plot3D)

colfun <- colorRampPalette( c("blue","cyan","orange","yellow") )
mycolors <- colfun(11)
persp3D(
    z=t(A),
    col=mycolors,
    border="black",
    theta=45+270,
    phi=15,
    zlim=c(0,1.5),
    colkey=FALSE,
    lwd=.3,
    ticktype="detailed",
    nticks=7,
    bty="b2"
)
```

[image]